# Dealing with multiple table in Excel Worksheet for Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am having a workbook that will constantly add on tables and I am unsure how to deal with this kind of cases in Power BI as I cannot select tables but only sheet. However, when using sheet some actions must be taken to clean the messy data before using it. I have no idea how to deal with this case. Appreciate if got any help at here!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Imagine there will be more and more tables similar add on below in the same sheet. This is the reason I cannot select table in Power BI as I will have to manually add in the table everytime. In this kind of case, how am I gonna deal with the sheet?

Comment: You would need to transform the data, promote the headers of the first table, then you can apply a filter on column Quantity to remove the blank and string "Quantity". That way you could have all the tables populated automatically. 

The problem with that is you will lose the "Y2023/Y2023" data. May I ask if there is a possibility to add an additional column "YEAR" to your tables ? an Excel formula maybe ?

Comment: @Xela Ya, I think that will be great to remove the title and adding it to additional column. Thanks for suggesting a way to do so!